# Layout problems with `tikzpicture[remember picture, overlay]` inside 2-column beamer `frame`

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

Context: [beamer: column + [overlay, remember picture] --> additional white vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360562/beamer-column-overlay-remember-picture-additional-white-vertical-space/488690#488690)

I have a layout problem when using `tikzpicture` with `[remember picture, overlay]` option inside a `column` of a `beamer` slide. 
1. Without the extra options the picture is laid out fine within the column. 
2. With the `[remember picture, overlay]` option, the `tikzpicture` overflows into the second column. I have to manually `hspace` and `vspace` it back into its column. Any suggestions for avoiding this behavior?

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Two column layout broken}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[c]{0.5\columnwidth}
      \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          ...
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}[c]{0.5\columnwidth}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! `[remember picture,overlay]` is precisely made for absolute page positioning or positioning w.r.t. to some landmarks, and to "turn off" the bounding box. Please do not use `\hspace` and the like in this context. Rather, please explain us what you want to achieve and provide a small document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: BTW, you can use [remember picture] without [overlay], and vice verses.  Remember picture stores the location of the origin in the aux file, which is why it takes two runs.  Overlay turns off the bounding box, like using \smash and \rlap or \llap.

Comment: I'm trying to use `tikzmark` with `tikzpicture` to remember the locations of certain spots inside the figure. Let me cookup a simple example.